Bulk symlink edit with rename.ul in both path and file target
For reason, I'm trying to copy a folder like this:
folder 100: 
100/file1001
100/file1002
...
100/file1009

folder: link100
link100/1001 -> 100/file1001
link100/1002 -> 100/file1002
...
link100/1009 -> 100/file1009

this is a simplistic example (the real one is with timestanp and hundred thousands of files), I'm trying to make a copy of those two folder and replace every instance of 100 by 200 even in the link path.
I've written a python script that do :
cp -r 100 200
rename.ul 100 200 200/*
cp -r link100 link200
rename.ul 100 200 link200/*
rename.ul -sa 100 200 link200/* 

But the command rename.ul -sa only replace in target file string not in the target path.
So I end up with my links looking like that:
folder: link200
link200/2001 -> 100/file2001
link200/2002 -> 100/file2002
...
link200/2009 -> 100/file2009

But I would expect something like this :
folder: link200
link200/2001 -> 200/file2001
link200/2002 -> 200/file2002
...
link200/2009 -> 200/file2009

Knowing that I'm talking about copying millions of files and link, is there a bulk way to use rename.ul to replace a string in sim-link destination (even in the path not only in the filename) or should I just recreate those link manually instead ?
If you have consideration of performance I'm interested.

Instead of trying to copy a symlink, how about you just create a new symlink.

@paladin I have millions of link to create which means list millions of files several time to recreate them but that's an option I'm considering as well

I would also ask myself, why do I want to use millions of symlinks? Maybe there is a more elegant solution to my problem. I know, sometimes it's not possible to use the elegant one.

@Kiwy but copying a symlink isn't easier for your system than creating a new one

Trust me if i had a choice to have literally a billion file and a billion simlink matching those file I would not have gone that path. Also this is only part of my problem as I also need to change the system time for every hour in the past year, but once more trust me I did not design this project I'm just testing it :-(

@paladin points out:

Instead of trying to copy a symlink, how about you just create a new symlink.

to which you reply:

I have millions of link to create which means list millions of files several time to recreate them but that's an option I'm considering as well

Well, but if you're changing them afterwards, copying and then changing them will take much longer than just directly creating them as they should be.
And: Copying symlink isn't even easier for your system than creating a new one, to begin with! If you look at what cp --no-derefence link100/1001 link200/2001 does it's this:
readlink("link100/1001", "…", 10)        = 9
symlinkat("…", AT_FDCWD, "link200/2001") = 0

in other words, cp itself has no other way to do this than read the symlink, memorize its target, and make a new symlink where you want the copy to appear.
So, use a programming language that you feel comfortable with, list the contents of the link100 folder once, do what you want with the paths and symlinks' targets and create the new, correct output directory when ready.
If these are really many files (and you claim they are), then I'd discourage you from doing this in a shell script where you handle each symlink individually: the time you need to start to spawn processes for each file will outweigh the time spend doing your intended filesystem operation.

It make sense that this would be easier to do. I don't want to but maybe listing the files once and replace a string for each new link ils a better approach. I'll let you know

Depending on the specific text transformation you need to accomplish in the filenames, the Perl rename utility may suffice.
This test creates 10,000 test files (which is the slowest part of the process), and then copies the 100 folder to the 200 folder, and symlinks each of the files in the 200 folder.
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo Create....
time for j in $(jot 10000)
do
  date > 100/file100"$j"
done
echo

echo Copy....
time cp -Rp 100/ 200/
echo

echo Rename....
time rename -d 's/^file100/file200/' -- 200/file100*
echo

echo Relink....
mkdir link200
time ln -s -- 200/* link200
echo

Resulting in:
$./test.sh 
Create....

real    0m21.819s
user    0m4.443s
sys     0m9.237s

Copy....

real    0m0.536s
user    0m0.048s
sys     0m0.487s

Rename....

real    0m0.183s
user    0m0.076s
sys     0m0.106s

Relink....

real    0m0.116s
user    0m0.016s
sys     0m0.101s

$ ls -l link200/file200{1,?1,?01,?001}
lrwx--x---  1 jim wheel 12 Jul 23 12:09 link200/file2001@ -> 200/file2001
lrwx--x---  1 jim wheel 15 Jul 23 12:09 link200/file2001001@ -> 200/file2001001
lrwx--x---  1 jim wheel 14 Jul 23 12:09 link200/file200101@ -> 200/file200101
lrwx--x---  1 jim wheel 13 Jul 23 12:09 link200/file20011@ -> 200/file20011
lrwx--x---  1 jim wheel 15 Jul 23 12:09 link200/file2002001@ -> 200/file2002001
lrwx--x---  1 jim wheel 14 Jul 23 12:09 link200/file200201@ -> 200/file200201
lrwx--x---  1 jim wheel 13 Jul 23 12:09 link200/file20021@ -> 200/file20021
lrwx--x---  1 jim wheel 15 Jul 23 12:09 link200/file2003001@ -> 200/file2003001
lrwx--x---  1 jim wheel 14 Jul 23 12:09 link200/file200301@ -> 200/file200301
lrwx--x---  1 jim wheel 13 Jul 23 12:09 link200/file20031@ -> 200/file20031
...
lrwx--x---  1 jim wheel 15 Jul 23 12:09 link200/file2008001@ -> 200/file2008001
lrwx--x---  1 jim wheel 14 Jul 23 12:09 link200/file200801@ -> 200/file200801
lrwx--x---  1 jim wheel 13 Jul 23 12:09 link200/file20081@ -> 200/file20081
lrwx--x---  1 jim wheel 15 Jul 23 12:09 link200/file2009001@ -> 200/file2009001
lrwx--x---  1 jim wheel 14 Jul 23 12:09 link200/file200901@ -> 200/file200901
lrwx--x---  1 jim wheel 13 Jul 23 12:09 link200/file20091@ -> 200/file20091

Also, note that the symlinks created in your example are broken.  For clarity, my code creates them in the same broken fashion.  If you want your symlinks to be valid, create them something like:
echo Fix symlinks....
mkdir fix200
( cd fix200; time ln -s -- ../200/* . )
echo

This produces:
$ ls -l fix200/file200{1,?1,?01,?001} | grep -v '[4-7]'
lrwx--x---  1 jim wheel 18 Jul 23 12:18 fix200/file2001001@ -> ../200/file2001001
lrwx--x---  1 jim wheel 18 Jul 23 12:18 fix200/file2002001@ -> ../200/file2002001
lrwx--x---  1 jim wheel 18 Jul 23 12:18 fix200/file2003001@ -> ../200/file2003001
lrwx--x---  1 jim wheel 18 Jul 23 12:18 fix200/file2008001@ -> ../200/file2008001
lrwx--x---  1 jim wheel 18 Jul 23 12:18 fix200/file2009001@ -> ../200/file2009001

And:
$ file link200/file2009995
link200/file2009995: broken symbolic link to 200/file2009995
$ file fix200/file2009995
fix200/file2009995: symbolic link to ../200/file2009995

